# Microsoft SQL-Apply "Where" Clause to Particular Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, where-clause, with-statement

I am trying to get the number of days that a person has total recording time over a certain amount for multiple amounts. Right now I am only able to get one column of accurate data for number of days(I am currently getting days over 60 in all of the days columns. Essentially I want to return a 0 for all persons not having any days for that particular recording length increment. I also want to get the number of days for all increments for persons having days with recording lengths in those increments.

Essentially I wish I could put the "Where" clause with column name as I define the column.(I know it doesn't work that way) What would the best way to be to tackle this problem?

Here is my code:

```
WITH CTERecordingsByDate AS
(
    SELECT      Person.FirstName,
                Person.LastName,
                CAST(Created AS DATE) AS Whole_Date,
                SUM(Length)/60 AS Recordings_Sum, --Length is in seconds
    FROM        Recordings
    JOIN        Person ON Recordings.PersonID=Person.ID
    WHERE       Created BETWEEN '2013-07-01 00:00:00.000' 
                        AND     '2013-08-01 00:00:00.000'
    GROUP BY    Person.FirstName, 
                Person.LastName,
                CAST(Created AS DATE)
)

SELECT      FirstName, 
            LastName, 
            COUNT(*) AS DaysAbove60
            COUNT(*) AS DaysAbove100
            COUNT(*) AS DaysAbove140
FROM        CTERecordingsByDate
WHERE       Recordings_Sum >= 60
AND         Recordings_Sum < 100
GROUP BY    FirstName, LastName
ORDER BY    COUNT(*) DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove your WHERE clause and use CASE inside your COUNT functions:

```
COUNT(case when Recordings_Sum >= 60 AND Recordings_Sum < 100 then 1 end) AS DaysAbove60
COUNT(case when Recordings_Sum >= 100 AND Recordings_Sum < 140 then 1 end) AS DaysAbove100
COUNT(case when Recordings_Sum >= 140 then 1 end) AS DaysAbove140
```